# How to expose docker container from Rancher's private network?

Tags: docker, rancher

Let's say that I have a HAProxy load-balancer inside Rancher's private network. Now I'd like to expose it somehow to the world, so it could receive requests from somewhere else apart of other docker containers living next to it.

If it was just a simple docker container than I probably should map port from docker container to some interface with IP address which is accessible from outside of docker network.

Probably I can do the same with container in Rancher, but this means that I have to configure network manually on every host where this container might run. And this kind of work is exactly what I'm trying to avoid using orchestration tool like Rancher.

How do you do that? How do you expose containers living inside of private network to the world?

Answer (score -1):

Use Load Balancer service, look at the documentation: http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/rancher-ui/applications/stacks/adding-balancers/

Comment: But this will be a load-balancer living in private network right? How do you expose it?

Comment: No, the load balancer exposes the docker image out on the _host_.  
So, if you run the lb on host1 and host2, both would expose the service out with the port you define in the lb setup.
I had a problem then loadbalancing those rancher load balancers, but I got answer on IRC that you just label some of the hosts and start the load balancers on those hosts (through labels on the load balancer setup) and expose those from a "front load balancer".